# how to read an integer array in MEX-function

Tags: matlab, mex

I am passing an integer array of uint8 type from MATLAB to a MEX-function. How do I read these values? I tried using:

```
int *n;
n = (int * ) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
```

but the values come out as junk. I also tried

```
double *n;
n= mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

and in this case junk values also appear.

What is the solution to this?

Basically I want to read the integer value in the MEX-function but `mxGetPr` returns double type.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the demo MEX-function explore.c, which you can open in MATLAB using

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mex/explore.c']);
```

In there you'll find a bunch of functions whose names all start with `analyze_` and then a type (for example, `analyze_uint8`). In those functions you'll see the output of calls to `mxGetData` being cast to a particular C type, like this:

```
pr = (unsigned char *)mxGetData(array_ptr);
```

`pr` now points to the real part of `array_ptr`, an array of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the number of bytes you read, and the interpretation of these bytes, is the same in the input data (that comes form Matlab) and in the output array (the array you read into in the mex function). Since `uint8` is 8 bits long, both `double` and `int` will read wrong number of bytes, and misinterpret these bytes.

Try to include `stdint.h` header, and use the `uint8_t` data type for the array you read into.