# How to pass an integer array from matlab to mex?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I want to pass an integer array from matlab to mex. The array is for example  `a=[1 2 3 4].` I wrote the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mkl.h>
#include "mkl_vml.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mkl_vsl.h"


/* main fucntion */
void mexFunction(int nlhs,  mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    int n, *a;

    /* make pointers to input data */
    n = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    a = (int *)mxGetData(prhs[1]);

    mexPrintf("a[0]:%d \t a[1]:%d \t a[2]:%d \n", a[0],a[1],a[2]);

}
```

When I run it the result is:

```
a[0]:0   a[1]:1072693248     a[2]:0
```

I've seen this answer :  [using integer arrays on mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783727/using-integer-arrays-on-mex) but I haven't understood what to do.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As in the duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783727/using-integer-arrays-on-mex, you need to pass `uint64(a)`, not just `a`. If that doesn't work or you don't understand, edit to give self-contained code for  exactly how you call your mex file from matlab, i.e. you need to expand on "When I run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a table is of equivalent C and MATLAB data types to use when deciding how to pass data.

[image]

[Source](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-arguments-to-shared-library-functions.html).

Since you are dealing with an `int *` in the MEX file, you should be passing `int32` MATLAB data.  Note however that `int` in C is not guaranteed to be 32-bit, but seems to be so on modern systems.

Comment: Thanks for the table. It was really useful.

Comment: @F.F. You're welcome.  Specifically, the MATLAB type to match a C `int` is probably `int32`.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Yours and @Ramashalanka. Thank you. I am sorry, I forgot to accept it.